In a Coxeter group, is $w$ the only element of minimal length in $wA_{In(w)}$?
Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system.
$In(w)=\{s\in S\,|\,l(ws)<l(w)\} $ and $A_{{In}(w)}=\{a\in W\,|\,l(a)<l(sa)\;\forall s\in In(w)\}$.
I'm wondering if it is true that $l(wa)\ge l(w)$ for all $a\in A_{In(w)}$, with $l(wa)=l(w)$ if and only if $a$ is the identity.
In other words, is it true that $w$ is the only element of minimal length in $wA_{In(w)}$?
(And, if not, can we say that for every $a\neq e$ there exists an element $u\in W_{In(w)}$ such that $l(wua)>l(w)$?)
My question arises from Lemma 8.3.3 ii of Davis's "The geometry and topology of Coxeter groups". Given a spherical subset $T\subset S$, it defines a retraction $p_T:W\rightarrow A_T$ that maps $w=w_1w_2$ (the unique decomposition with $w_1\in W_T$ and $w_2\in A_T$) to $w_2$. This lemma asserts that, given a starlike (with respect to the identity e) subset $U\subset W$ with $w$ extreme element, then $p_{In(w)}(w^{-1}(W\setminus U))=A_{In(w)}\setminus\{e\}$.
But, it seems to me that in the proof only one inclusion ($\subset$) is proven. The other one ($\supset$) would follows from $w$ being the only element of minimal length in $wA_{In(w)}$ (because, in this case, for every $a\in A_{In(w)}$, $a\neq e$, the element $wa$ would be in $W\setminus U$ and $p_{In(w)}(w^{-1}wa)=a$).

What is wrong with the serial closers on this website? None of them seem to be experts on Coxeter groups but still voted to close. I’m voting to reopen.

No need to be an expert on Coxeter groups to see that the post was a PSQ. After "context" was added (before your comment), it was naturally reopened (also by non-"experts").

@AnneBauval I think you (and all the other police on this site) need to stop with the ‘context’ excuse. There’s no need to add every single thing under the Sun that you tried to sufficiently advanced questions. On the other hand, a question written ‘with context’ doesn’t automatically make it good.

If you want to change the rules, you can discuss them on meta. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/
